# cd tray get ejected automatically Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lts, cd

I'm facing this problem since two months. If it is due to any hardware problem can I disable opening of tray forever using any command.

Answer (score 0):

```
eject -i on
```

This option controls locking of the hardware  eject  button.  When enabled, the drive will not be ejected when the button is pressed. This is useful when you are carrying a laptop in a bag or case and don't want it to eject if the button is inadvertently pressed.

Source: `man eject`

Comment: ran this command. but still button is working.

Comment: Then I'm afraid, I can't help you anymore.